# Regular Expressions - Read through Text Doc and Extract Sentences with a Specific Word

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp

I have a series of large text documents.  I need to read through them and - if a particular word appears - extract the entire sentence.

So, if I'm searching for the word `wobble` and a sentence in the document is `Weebles wobble but they don't fall down`, I want to extract that sentence.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

I can think of two approaches to this:

1. Search the document for the word, then extract the particular sentence; or
2. Iterate through each sentence in the document.  Check each sentence for the word.  If the sentence has the word extract the sentence.

I would think 1 is more computationally efficient than 2. But not sure what the syntax would be.

Is there another approach I'm not considering?

Any help on efficiency and syntax appreciated.

Comment: Are you after precision or efficiency (=speed)? Use Approach #2, it is just more precise.

Answer (score 1):

you first need to get proper sentences from text document the best way of doing that is using nltk.data tokenizer first make sure that you have installed python nltk library properly.

```
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
txt = open("txt_file.txt")
data = txt.read()
all_sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(data)
required_sentences = []
for each_sentence in all_sentences:
    if 'wobble' in each_sentence:
        required_sentences.append(each_sentence)
print(required_sentences)
```

Comment: I saw the following response elsewhere using a list comprehension:

>>> txt = "I like to eat apple. Me too. Let's go buy some apples."
>>> [sentence + '.' for sentence in txt.split('.') if 'apple' in sentence]
['I like to eat apple.', " Let's go buy some apples."]

I'm thinking this is not a computationally efficient as nltk but more efficient than a standard 'for' loop?

Comment: yes i am considering a large text document where you can not easily point out where sentnce is being completed you need some sementics to break sentences nltk can do this easily.